# CSS (scrolling): why is it not possible to base the command on class name instead of id?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, scrollbar

I wanted to make a topbar reacting to scrolling on the website.

I have used this command:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
//    SMALL!!
    document.getElementById("logo_nav_bar").style.height = " 100px";    
}  
//  BIG!!
   else {
    document.getElementById("logo_nav_bar").style.height = "160px";
}
```

**Question**:
do I have to always use getElementById? because getElementsByClassName did not work and I would like to apply this command to the whole class.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **list** of elements. You have to iterate through the list to change each element individually.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! :)
how would the code look like then? do I have to use some kind of indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are not using jQuery, You can try following: Replace className with your class, and change required attribute, I changed color for a sample.

```
function scrollFunction() {
   if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
      //    SMALL!!
      var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
      for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
          elements[i].style.color = "yellow";
      }
   }  
//  BIG!!
   else {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");
    for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, Hamza! It solved my problem and work perfectly!